# Parsing Json Output correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to correctly target the elements within the Json Output and I am getting closer but I presume there is a easy and obvious way I am missing.

My Json looks like this with a upper level event.

**JSON SNIPPET UPDATED**

```
chat =     (
            (
                    {
            Key = senderId;
            Value =                 {
                Type = 0;
                Value = "eu-west-1:91afbc3f-890a-4160-8903-688bf0e9efe8";
            };
        },
                    {
            Key = chatId;
            Value =                 {
                Type = 0;
                Value = "eu-west-1:be6457ce-bac1-412d-9307-e375e52e22ff";
            };
        },
                    {
            Key = timestamp;
            Value =                 {
                Type = 1;
                Value = 1430431197;
            };
        },

//Continued
```

I am targeting this level using

```
NSArray *chat = array[@"chat"];

for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in chat )
{
    NSLog(@"---- %@", theCourse);

    // I tried the following to target the values 
    //NSLog(@"chatId: %@", [theCourse valueForKey:@"Key"]);
    //NSLog(@"timestamp: %@", theCourse[@"senderId"] ); 
} 
}
```

I need to parse the value data for each key which if I was using an array would do like `[theCourse valueForKey:@"Key"]` but I think I may not be going deep enough?

As you would expect, `[theCourse valueForKey:@"Key"]` gives me the Key values but I need the associate values of those keys.

Comment: It doesn't look like chat is an array of dictionaries. It looks like an array of arrays of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an easier dictionary:

```
NSArray *chat = array[@"chat"][0];
NSMutableDictionary* newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* d in chat)
    [newDict setValue:d[@"Value"][@"Value"] forKey:d[@"Key"]];
```

Now you can use the `newDict`.

```
NSLog(@"chatId: %@", [newDict valueForKey:@"chatId"]);
```

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do but it produces a `__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` error

Comment: Cheers. Updated above

Comment: That works. Only gives me 1 iteration instead of every `chatId` in the JSON but I think thats a problem for another time! Thanks